# How to redirect to 404 error page via JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, redirect

The site consists of index.php only and content changes via JavaScript, when ever I type in a random address instead of some real navigation links it just shows me the header, no content, no redirect. 
Having `ErrorDocument 404 /404.html` in .htaccess doesn't help.

Is there a way to solve this?

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine on
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?q=$1 [NE,L]

  ErrorDocument 404 /404.html

</IfModule>
```

Comment: It's not clear to me what you are asking... can you rephrase?

Comment: If you can't find the page, how can you load the JavaScript ?

Comment: How are you changing the contents with JavaScript? Some code would be helpful.

Answer (score 3):

Javascript would require an actual page to be loaded... If you are getting a 404, no javascript will be available to handle a redirect.

Does your webhost support custom .htaccess files? Is it supposed to be named something else? Also, make sure that the .htaccess is in the root directory of your web page so it will contain all sub folders.

If you want to combine the .htaccess with javascript, try this:

```
ErrorDocument 404 "<script>//do something</script>"
```

**EDIT**

Because of this line in your .htaccess

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?q=$1 [NE,L]
```

You will NEVER get an actual 404 error. The reason for this is that a url such as 'www.example.com/page1' will redirect to: 'www.example.com/index.php?q=page1'

To combat the error page not loading, in you PHP script that detects the 'q' variable do the following:

```
if($_REQUEST['q'] == ""){
    //Show the home page
}else if($_REQUEST['q'] == "portfolio"){
    //Show portfolio page
}else{
    //No page for provided arguments, show an error or redirect to error page.
}
```

Comment: Okay, so without looking at your .htaccess, it appears as if you are using some RewriteRules. So any extra arguments will be sent back to the index as a variable, correct? This being said, it does not matter what the URL is, it will always point back to the Index, you will never actually hit a non-found page. Can you post your .htaccess?

Comment: Look at what I added to my post.